# Can I render another partial view in a partial view by specifying relative path with Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-6.0

I have a Razor Pages project (no Controller) with structure like this:

[image]

From the main `Index.cshtml`, I would render a partial view for its content depend on the Theme name, for example:

```
@* Default will be replaced with theme name *@
<partial name="Themes\Default\HomeContent" />
```

In `HomeContent.cshtml`, I would like to render many other partial views within its folder. However this wouldn't work:

```
<p>Content</p>

<partial name="_DefaultThemePartial" />
```

The engine only searches these locations (correct [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0#partial-view-discovery)):

> InvalidOperationException: The partial view '_DefaultThemePartial' was
> not found. The following locations were searched:
>
> /Pages/_DefaultThemePartial.cshtml
>
> /Pages/Shared/_DefaultThemePartial.cshtml
>
> /Views/Shared/_DefaultThemePartial.cshtml

I have also tried `<partial name="./_DefaultThemePartial" />` or `<partial name=".\_DefaultThemePartial" />` or try putting them in a subfolder named `Shared` (within the Default folder). None of them works, only the above 3 locations are searched.

Is there anyway to render those partials without specifying the full path?

Comment: Why don't you want to give the full path?

Comment: @PoulBak it may change in the future and repeating a hard string path is not a good idea.

Comment: You might change the paths to use a variable, which you can define globally somewhere. Not ideal, but then you only have to change one value, if needed.

Comment: @PoulBak yeah that's one thing I thought about if there is no better solution. In the end I think it's just not worth it and I just use the `LocationExpander` I created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a response from my [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39014#issuecomment-993834984), there's a simpler solution without any extra code by adding the `.cshtml` at the end:

> [...] This is by design. Partial view lookup is done in two ways:
>
> - By name
> - By file path
>
> You've done the lookup by name (without file extension), if you want
> to use a relative path, make sure you specify the file extension.
>
> ```
> <partial name="_DefaultThemePartial.cshtml" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I posted [a proposal here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39014). In the meantime, I found out you can expand the discovery mechanism by using `IViewLocationExpander` but I barely found any useful documentation on it.

```cs
public class PartialViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        if (!context.Values.TryGetValue("FromView", out var fromView))
        {
            return viewLocations;
        }

        var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(fromView) ?? "/";
        var name = context.ViewName;
        if (!name.EndsWith(".cshtml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            name += ".cshtml";
        }

        var path = Path.Combine(folder, name)
            .Replace('\\', '/');

        return viewLocations.Concat(new[] { path });
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
        var ctx = context.ActionContext as ViewContext;
        if (ctx == null) { return; }

        var path = ctx.ExecutingFilePath;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            context.Values["FromView"] = path;
            context.Values["ViewName"] = context.ViewName;
        }
    }
}

// Register
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new PartialViewLocationExpander());
});
```